# DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE inside update statement throwing invalid data type error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Why does a select work but an update throws invalid data?

```
DECLARE
    L_NUMBER NUMBER;
    L_NUMBER_TABLE DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE;
    L_LAST_PRINTED_DATE DATE := SYSDATE;
BEGIN
    L_NUMBER_TABLE(0) := 1033000;

-- THIS WORKS
SELECT TB.COLUMN_VALUE
INTO L_NUMBER
FROM TABLE(L_NUMBER_TABLE) TB;

-- THIS DOES NOT WORK
--  ERROR AT LINE 1
--  ORA-00902: INVALID DATATYPE
--  ORA-06512: AT LINE 13
UPDATE SCHEMA.REAL_NUMBER_TABLE
SET    REAL_NUMBER_DATE           = L_LAST_PRINTED_DATE
WHERE  EXISTS (  SELECT TB.COLUMN_VALUE
                    FROM TABLE( L_NUMBER_TABLE ) TB
                    WHERE TB.COLUMN_VALUE = REAL_NUMBER_COLUMN );


END;
```

I'm trying to loop thru a cursor and update the last printed date of the primary sequence found inside the cursor. I tried looping thru the cursor but then when I returned the cursor to the client, it throws an out of index error. So I was forced to make two cursors, one to loop thru and one to return. My goal is to learn what's the easiest and most maintainable way to hold collections for updating tables.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR L_ORIGINAL_CURSOR IS SELECT ...

    L_CURSOR_COLUMN_1    PLS_INTEGER;
    L_CURSOR_COLUMN_2    PLS_INTEGER;
    L_CURSOR_COLUMN_3    PLS_INTEGER;
    -- Keep adding or removing the number of columns to match...1/2 09182019515PM
    -- L_CURSOR_COLUMN_4    PLS_INTEGER;
    L_NUMBER_TABLE DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE;
    L_COUNTER PLS_INTEGER;
    L_LAST_PRINTED_DATE DATE := SYSDATE;
BEGIN    
    OPEN L_ORIGINAL_CURSOR;
        LOOP
            -- Keep adding or removing the number of columns to match... 2/2 09182019515PM
            FETCH L_ORIGINAL_CURSOR INTO L_CURSOR_COLUMN_1, L_CURSOR_COLUMN_2, L_CURSOR_COLUMN_3; -- , L_CURSOR_COLUMN_4;
                IF L_ORIGINAL_CURSOR%NOTFOUND THEN
                    EXIT;
                END IF;

                IF L_ORIGINAL_CURSOR%FOUND THEN
                        -- CURRENT SOLUTION IS TO UPDATE HERE BOUNCING BETWEEN SQL AND PLSQL ENGINES
                        -- UPDATE ....
                    -- WANTED IMPLEMENTATION
                    L_COUNTER := L_COUNTER + 1;
                END IF;
                -- WANTED IMPLEMENTATION STORE PK IN MY COLLECTION
                L_NUMBER_TABLE(L_COUNTER) := L_CURSOR_COLUMN_1;
        END LOOP;

    -- IF COLLECTION IS BIGGER THAN 0
    IF L_NUMBER_TABLE.COUNT > 0 THEN
        -- SCRIPT BREAKS HERE
        UPDATE ...
        SET ... = L_LAST_PRINTED_DATE
        WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT TB.COLUMN_VALUE
                        FROM TABLE(L_NUMBER_TABLE) TB
                        WHERE TB.COLUMN_VALUE = ...   );
    END IF;
    CLOSE L_ORIGINAL_CURSOR;

    OPEN L_CURSOR FOR SELECT ...
END SP_GET_PM_WORK_ORDERS;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Currently the inline single sql update statement works but requires multiple engine hops between the SQL and PLSQL engines. Why am I allowed to do selects but not updates with my number table?

**DATABASE VERSION: 12.1.0.2.0**

Comment: Is REAL_NUMBER_DATE a date field?

Comment: I would use `where real_number_column member of l_number_table`. However, I am not sure whether it works with index-by table.

Comment: @alexherm yes, REAL_NUMBER_DATE is an oracle DATE field.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I tried it and received expression is of wrong type errors no matter how I tried it in the query.

Comment: what about TB.COLUMN_VALUE = REAL_NUMBER_COLUMN?  Both numbers?

Comment: @alexherm Yes, I even tried converting them both to number and strings. TO_NUMBER(TB.COLUMN_VALUE) = TO_NUMBER(REAL_NUMBER_COLUMN) and same for strings.

Comment: Why are you using a PL/SQL associative array ([`DMBS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#CHDGFFAD)) rather than an SQL collection (`CREATE TYPE number_table AS TABLE OF NUMBER;`) or a `VARRAY` ([`SYS.ODCINUMBERTABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcicnstnts.htm#sthref955))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#CHDGFFAD) is a PL/SQL associative array defined in the `DBMS_SQL` package as:

> ```sql
> TYPE number_table IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
> ```

This is a PL/SQL data type and should not work in SQL statements (I've yet to work out why your first statement works).

If you want a data type that works in SQL then you need to be using a collection (without the `INDEX BY`; also called a nested table data type):

> ```sql
> CREATE TYPE number_table IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
> ```

Or a fixed-length `VARRAY`:

> ```sql
> CREATE TYPE number_array IS VARRAY(10) OF NUMBER;
> ```

For example:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE real_number_table ( real_number_column, real_number_date ) AS
  SELECT 1033000, DATE '2019-01-01' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TYPE number_table IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

**PL/SQL Statement 1**:

Then your SQL statement will work with a collection data type:

```sql
DECLARE
  L_NUMBER NUMBER;
  L_NUMBER_TABLE NUMBER_TABLE;
  L_LAST_PRINTED_DATE DATE := SYSDATE;
BEGIN
  L_NUMBER_TABLE := NUMBER_TABLE();
  L_NUMBER_TABLE.EXTEND;
  L_NUMBER_TABLE( L_NUMBER_TABLE.COUNT ) := 1033000;

  UPDATE REAL_NUMBER_TABLE
  SET    REAL_NUMBER_DATE = L_LAST_PRINTED_DATE
  WHERE  EXISTS (
    SELECT TB.COLUMN_VALUE
    FROM TABLE( L_NUMBER_TABLE ) TB
    WHERE TB.COLUMN_VALUE = REAL_NUMBER_COLUMN
  );
END;
/
```

and then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM real_number_table;
```

outputs:

> ```
> REAL_NUMBER_COLUMN | REAL_NUMBER_DATE
> -----------------: | :---------------
>            1033000 | 09-OCT-19
> ```

**PL/SQL Statement 2**:

Or you can simplify it and use the `MEMBER OF` operator (this only works with collection data types and not `VARRAY`s):

```sql
DECLARE
  L_NUMBER NUMBER;
  L_NUMBER_TABLE NUMBER_TABLE := NUMBER_TABLE( 1033000 );
  L_LAST_PRINTED_DATE DATE := SYSDATE + 1;
BEGIN
  UPDATE REAL_NUMBER_TABLE
  SET    REAL_NUMBER_DATE = L_LAST_PRINTED_DATE
  WHERE  REAL_NUMBER_COLUMN MEMBER OF L_NUMBER_TABLE;
END;
/
```

and then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM real_number_table;
```

outputs:

> ```
> REAL_NUMBER_COLUMN | REAL_NUMBER_DATE
> -----------------: | :---------------
>            1033000 | 10-OCT-19
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b906aa9410b6d1ac9568f38a5b831585)*

---

You final PL/SQL anonymous block could be re-written as:

```sql
DECLARE
  L_NUMBER_TABLE NUMBER_TABLE;
  L_LAST_PRINTED_DATE DATE := SYSDATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT column1
  BULK COLLECT INTO L_NUMBER_TABLE
  FROM   your_table; -- as per L_ORIGINAL_CURSOR

  IF L_NUMBER_TABLE.COUNT > 0 THEN
    UPDATE other_table
    SET    date_column = L_LAST_PRINTED_DATE
    WHERE  number_column MEMBER OF L_NUMBER_TABLE;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Is there any way I can avoid creating a table?

Comment: @Matt If you are using an `UPDATE` statement then it will refer to a table. If you mean something else then you will have to clarify what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, I just understood CREATE TYPE number_table IS TABLE OF NUMBER;. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: So I can't just declare TYPE L_NUMBER_TYPE IS TABLE OF NUMBER; inside my package?

Comment: @Matt No, it needs to be defined in an SQL context not a PL/SQL context. Oracle 11g: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6337ae8bbdf65350a11a93f6084dccfe) and if you change the database to Oracle 18c [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6337ae8bbdf65350a11a93f6084dccfe) then the PL/SQL block using the type from the package does not even run.

Answer (score 0):

MT0 has provided a valid solution. In case `REAL_NUMBER_COLUMN` is a unique/primary Key then you could also use this (rather unknown) version:

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT REAL_NUMBER_COLUMN, REAL_NUMBER_DATE
    FROM SCHEMA.REAL_NUMBER_TABLE 
       JOIN TABLE(L_NUMBER_TABLE) ON COLUMN_VALUE = REAL_NUMBER_COLUMN
    )
SET REAL_NUMBER_DATE = L_LAST_PRINTED_DATE;
```